# How to add trace id to each logs in go micro service

Tags: go, logging, microservices, trace

I wanted to add trace id to logging done for each request to the micro service.I want this in similar as for springboot application we can set trace id in MDC and fetch it and use it while logging.

I have done some research and I found that MDC equivalent in go lang is context. So, I have set the trace id in my context. Now the problem is where ever I have to log with trace id ,I need to pass context to that function which is very ugly way. I am looking for a better solution for this problem.

```
func HandlerFunction(f gin.HandlerFunc) gin.HandlerFunc{
    return func(cxt *gin.Context) {
        reqraceId := cxt.Request.Header.Get("trace-id")
        requid , _ := uuid.NewRandom()

        if reqTraceId == "" {
            c.Request.Header.Set("trace-id", requid.String())
        }

        f(c)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might be worth reading up on `context.Context` particularly [this article](https://blog.golang.org/context) which has a section that says:

> At Google, we require that Go programmers pass a Context parameter as the first argument to every function on the call path between incoming and outgoing requests.

TL;DR - it's fine to pass the context, but what's the best way?

There's two main patterns

1. Ask the context to give you a logger
2. Give the logger the context

Context can be used to store values:

```
context.WithValue(ctx, someKey, someValue)
```

This means we can either do:

```
somepackage.Log(ctx).Info("hello world")
// or
sompackage.Info(ctx, "hello world")
```

The implementation of these two sample APIs could interact with the context to retrieve the values required with out needing to worry about the extra information that would have been in MDC at any of the logging call sites.

Comment: so we can pass the context and use it , there is not way to implement it in AOP way.

Comment: I do precisely the #1, up to the syntax itself :) log.Log(ctx).Info(...). Passing context in all methods on the path of request execution: yes again; took some time to get used to method signatures always including extra thing, but now it’s automatic. I also tied my impl of MDC into this.

Answer (score 1):

From my side I found that using the default log package we could set a prefix as `log.SetPrefix(traceId)`, doing so, the log will print the trace id as the prefix in the actual and sub-functions/structs.

```
import (
    "log"
    "github.com/google/uuid"
)

func (hdl *HTTPHandler) example() {
    var traceId string = uuid.NewString()
    log.SetPrefix(traceId + " - ")
    log.SetFlags(log.LstdFlags)
    // ...
    // ...
    log.Println("......")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue can also be solved using a dependency injection container.

We can implement "request-scoped" injections, and as a result, for each request, we will recreate all dependency tree that uses request-scoped dependency(logger, error reporter, clients which send requests to another service with context propagation).

But as I understood using dependency injection containers is not a best practice in go and not an "idiomatic" way.

Also, this approach can have some performance and memory issues since we will recreate objects for each request.